# Strange server response

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a sitw built using codeigniter using htaccess. But on some requests are really strange. The include one specific file(trough codeigniter) at the begginning. This happens really often, if cache is tured off. It happens with different files and doens't matter if the file is on filesystem or request goes trough codeigniter. I guess there something up with htacccess, but i'm not sure.I'll include htaccess and screenshot from fiddler on the bottom:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    #Options -Indexes

    #Force non-www
    RewriteCond      %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
    RewriteRule      ^(.*)$   http://%1/$1   [R=301,L]

    #If image, javascript or css file does not exists, then try application folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(images|js|css)/(.*)$ ./application/$1/$2 [L]  

    #If javascript or css file exists, send it to minifier
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.(js|css))$ ./standalone/min/?f=$1$2 [L]

    #If isn't file or folder then send it to codeigniter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 ./index.php
</IfModule>
```

And as you can see original request is to `top-bar-large.png` and echoing `$_SERVER` out from coudeigniter, shows "upper request" is to `parim.js`. And parim.js should javascript file after all. Any ideas?
[image: Response shown on fiddler]

Comment: Is it possible that your `parim.js` contains AJAX code and queries goes from that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP_SELF is index.php... so it seems like you are be getting a CI error page on which the js files are included.

By default, codeigniter comes with an .htaccess file in the `application` directory with `Deny all`; so anything in those folders will not be publicly accessible (including your images folder in there) unless you've modified it.

Also, make make sure the images exist.

Comment: Images does exists, when i open the image on new tab and refresh it several times, everything works fine. Bur when it's in page(css background-image), it hides randomly. On every refresho n page hides different image from page.